# SSRS excel header

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2012

When I export excel using SSRS 2012 from **JAVA SDK** (not from Visual studio or SSRS server report manager) , header right most part is not getting displayed fully.

For example if I  want to display 5 lines on the header three on right side and two on left side, second line in the left is not getting displayed fully.

Note: I am extracting excel output from SSRS and storing it as bit array in DB then flushing into excel in java.

Comment: I don't see why the result would differ if you store the report in the DB then save it instead of saving it directly. The Excel file has been generated by SSRS and this is only what matters. You can check it by exporting the Excel directly. That said, it would be easier to understand your issue with an image.